# Crawling a specific link on a page with multiple links?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to collect a specific link to visit it later throughout my script, but there are many links on the page I'm crawling and they all have the same a href tag.

How can I select one specifically? The site is bbb.org and my code is below.

Example, search `lamps` on bbb and i want to collect the links embedded with the business names so i can visit their profiles later.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def bbb_spider(max_pages):
bus_cat = raw_input('Enter a business category: ')
pages = 1
while pages <= max_pages:
    url = 'http://www.bbb.org/search/?type=category&input=' + str(bus_cat) + '&page=' + str(pages)
    sauce_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = sauce_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        href = link.get('href')
        print(href)
    pages += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the links located inside `h4` elements which are inside the *search results table*. There are different ways to get to them, but I would make a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("table.search-results-table tr h4 a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created something similar like this.
Look at my example for a crawler.
https://github.com/shiva1791/Python_webcrawler

The code takes the url it needs to parse from link.csv.
All the logic behind parsing every link on the page is in webcrawler.py file.